# Instance enters a freeze/hung state intermittently

Tags: sql-server

I currently have an issue in SQL Server and I'm not able to wrap my head around what actually is the cause.

So a bit of a background, we are co-hosting several applications in the same Windows Failover Cluster. For the past weeks we have gotten timeouts that are 58 seconds long on intermittent occasions.

From what I have gathered we can see the issue on three different databases on the same server.

We have also captured quite a lot of performance counters from the actual Windows Server, so I can safely say that the server does not have a general performance issue when it comes to CPU, Memory, Storage (DELL EMC SAN).

From the Profiler traces I've been running I can clearly find the issue but I don't understand what might cause it and here I seek guidance.

If you look at the picture [image: Profiler Trace Issue], you can see that I've used the where clause to specify the XactSequence and ordered it by EventSequence. The rows that I've marked 632 & 633 you can see that we have RCP:Completed and then it takes 58 seconds before SQL starts the with the next one in line RCP:Started.

We have done some tweaking with Maxdop as per MS recommendation, as well as changing MS DTC from Mutual Authentication to No Authentication but other that we are clueless right now to be honest.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150437/discussion-on-question-by-daw-instance-enters-a-freeze-hung-state-intermittently); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.